# Clicar em um h3 e focar em um campo do form

Tags: html, html5, formulário

Estou organizando um formulário de contato, dividido em várias partes.

Uma das coisas que preciso seria que quando o usuário clicasse em um h3 (mas pode ser também uma div, ancora ou button) um campo específico deste formulário ficasse focado.

Como eu conseguiria realizar isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para usares um `h3` podes fazer uso de uma ancora associada ao ID do `input`.

Seria assim:

```html
<h3><a href="#a">Clica-me para o input A</a></h3>
<h3><a href="#b">Clica-me para o input B</a></h3>

<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
```

ou [como o @ricardo também sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145663/129) usar o `label` assim:

```html
<label for="a">
    <h3>Clica-me para o input A</h3>
</label>
<label for="b">
    <h3>Clica-me para o input B</h3>
</label>

<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
```

E nestes casos não faz diferença onde na página os elementos estão desde que cada ID seja único (não repetido dentro da página).

Comment: Sergio o meu click não está a focar na tua primeira opção... Talvez seja aqui da snipped built-in do SO

Comment: @Miguel é possivel, ele é meio bugado :) Podes testar aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/eon3x98u/

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas formas de você resolver seu problema.
A mais simples seria utilizando elementos `HTML`, assim:

```html
<label for="minha_input"><h3>Input</h3></label>
<input type="text" id="minha_input">
```

Caso não queira, uma alternativa é fazer via **Java Script**, assim:

```js
function myFocus() {
  document.getElementById('minha_input').focus();
}
```

```html
 <h3 onclick="myFocus()">Input</h3>
<input type="text" id="minha_input">
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Dei `+1` pela sugestão de `label` mas não vejo razão para usar JavaScript quando o HTML tem maneiras nativas para fazer isso.

Comment: Concordo plenamente @Sergio. Dei +1 na sua resposta também, pois não tinha ciência de que o href usando *#* identificava o id da input.